# Place Name from Form Results in thank you page?

Tags: php, confirmation

I designed a form that emails the results when submitted.  The PHP script will show a thank you page upon success.  Is it possible to place the the "name" field in a separate thank you page?

Here is my code for the form:

```
<?php
$name = $_REQUEST['name'] ;
$carenumber= $_REQUEST['carenumber'] ;
$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$topic = $_REQUEST['topic'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

$Body = "";
$Body .= "Name: ";
$Body .= $name;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Caregiver Number: ";
$Body .= $carenumber;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Email Address: ";
$Body .= $email;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Topic: ";
$Body .= $topic;
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "\n";
$Body .= "Message: ";
$Body .= $message;
$Body .= "\n";

mail( "eriksnet@mac.com", "Message From Myorphan.com Contact Page",
$Body, "From: $email" );

header( "Location: http://www.feedmyorphan.com/contact_confirm.htm" );
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to make the thank you page a PHP page (using the .php extension), then, in your header in this code sample you have provided, place:

```
header("Location: http://www.feedmyorphan.com/contact_confirm.php?name=" . urlencode($name));
```

Then, on the thank you page, use `<?php echo $_GET['name'] ?>` anywhere on the page.

Comment: Ok... But in the thank you page, do I simply place  $name anywhere on the page?

Comment: `<?php echo $_GET['name']; ?>`

Comment: It doesn't work:  <div class="mr">Thank you echo $_GET['name'];</div>

Comment: Do I need something in the header of the thank you page?  How do i make reference to the echo?  Thanks for all your help

Comment: You need to use PHP tags around the call.

Comment: Like this:  <echo $_GET['name'];>

Comment: See my revised comment above.

Comment: Thank you.. it worked great.  Should this work with all the browsers?  Thank you so much for your follow through!  Wonderful.

Comment: This method doesn't have to do with browsers since it is all server side. It isn't very safe, though, because anyone can change the name value in the address bar and insert whatever information into your page that they'd like, including malicious code. I'd use the session method shown in my answer below.

Comment: Use: <p> <?php echo $_GET['name'] ?> </p> - But Dave Kiss is correct regarding the security of this method; the session should be started on the page that contains the form and ended on the thank you page.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

...try setting the name field as a $_SESSION variable, and accessing it through $_SESSION on the thank you page.

Comment: Do you have an example?  Not sure how to follow.

Comment: Here is a good tutorial on using session variables:

http://www.w3schools.com/PHP/php_sessions.asp

This will enable you to access the name variable on any page, providing the session is started correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to use SESSIONS and send the cookie data to the second script using PHP. Here is an example using cURL.

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['name'] = $name;   
passSession();

function passSession(){
 $strCookie = 'PHPSESSID=' . $_COOKIE['PHPSESSID'] . '; path=/';
 session_write_close();

 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"http://www.feedmyorphan.com/contact_confirm.php");
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIE, $strCookie);
 curl_exec ($ch);
 curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Then, in your second script, call for the session and echo the session variable

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['name'];
```

Also, be sure to validate and sanitize your input to ensure the data being submitted is as accurate as possible.